# AngularJS Ui Router regex matching wildcard in url

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, url-routing, angular-ui-router

I wonder if this is possible - I need to match the following URLs with one pattern:

```
/one/app/home
/one/two/app/home
/one/two/three/app/home
...
```

I understand that AngularJS routing doesn't support regex, but [Angular UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) does.

```
main.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/fail");
    $stateProvider
    .state("home", {
        url: "{.+}/app/home",
        templateUrl: "assets/tpl/home.html",
        controller: "homeController"
    })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

This doesn't work though (goes to `/fail` with all the examples). Is what I want to do possible at all?

Comment: Use `.+` instead of `{.+}`, and add a `$` at the end to ensure the `app/home` part is the last one: `.+/app/home$`

Comment: @Robin I think there are certain limitations of URL parsing here not allowing this to work.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't familiar with [Angular UI regex syntax](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters)... As a random thought I'd say it doesn't work either because the "name" part is mandatory (`{id:...}`), or because the regex can't include a `/` (ie it's only applied between to slashes). But I'm not familiar with the specifics, so this is just a guess in the wild. Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

You should use it like this:

```
state("home", {
    url: "/{beginPath:.+}{endPath:/app/home}",
    templateUrl: "assets/tpl/home.html",
    controller: "homeController"
});
```

Then you you will have access to `$stateParams.beginPath` (which is equal to evertyhing before *`/app/home/`*) and to `$stateParams.endPath` which will be equal to *`/app/home/`*

If `/one/` is necessary in the beggining then use something like this:

```
url: "/{beginPath:one/.+}{endPath:/app/home}"
```

Comment: Can i use it with angular native router?

Comment: Although you cannot use advanced regex syntax, you can solve this particular task using angular native `ngRoute`.

To match any url that ends with `/app/home` use this: <br/>
`$routeProvider.when('/:beginPath*\/app/home', { ... }'`

To match any url that ends with `/app/home` and starts with '/one' use this:  <br/>`$routeProvider.when('/one/:beginPath*\/app/home', { ... }'`

Comment: stupid comment formatting. 
    Anyway, you'll get access to everything before '/app/home' in `$routeParams` in your controller.

Comment: I have tried same however this does not work when you reload or refresh your page or directly place url in address bar.
Do we have any option to solve this problem